# Why does Mockito complain about misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue when the parameters are correct?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, android-testing

I am running my login unit tests which keep returning errors :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ObservableJust cannot be returned by doServerLoginApiCall()
doServerLoginApiCall() should return Single
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

I am not sure why that throws, even when I cross checked everything is correct even though tests keep failing due to the above reason. Here's my code: 
LoginPresenterTest:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    LoginMvpView mMockLoginMvpView;
    @Mock
    DataManager mMockDataManager;

    private LoginPresenter<LoginMvpView> mLoginPresenter;
    private TestScheduler mTestScheduler;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void onlyOnce() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        mTestScheduler = new TestScheduler();
        TestSchedulerProvider testSchedulerProvider = new TestSchedulerProvider(mTestScheduler);
        mLoginPresenter = new LoginPresenter<>(
            mMockDataManager,
            testSchedulerProvider,
            compositeDisposable);
        mLoginPresenter.onAttach(mMockLoginMvpView);
    }

    @Test
    public void testServerLoginSuccess() {

        String email = "dummy@gmail.com";
        String password = "password";

        LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();

        doReturn(Observable.just(loginResponse))
                .when(mMockDataManager)
                .doServerLoginApiCall(new LoginRequest
                        .ServerLoginRequest(email, password));

        mLoginPresenter.onServerLoginClick(email, password);

        mTestScheduler.triggerActions();

        verify(mMockLoginMvpView).showLoading();
        verify(mMockLoginMvpView).hideLoading();
        verify(mMockLoginMvpView).openMainActivity();
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mLoginPresenter.onDetach();
    }
```

Here is my testscheduleprovider :

```
public class TestSchedulerProvider implements SchedulerProvider {

    private final TestScheduler mTestScheduler;

    public TestSchedulerProvider(TestScheduler testScheduler) {
        this.mTestScheduler = testScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Scheduler ui() {
        return mTestScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Scheduler computation() {
        return mTestScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Scheduler io() {
        return mTestScheduler;
    }

}
```

The error is thrown at LoginPresentertest at the line

```
 .doServerLoginApiCall(new LoginRequest
                        .ServerLoginRequest(email, password));
```

Any idea how I can alter this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your `doServerLoginApiCall` returns single, but you're trying to mock it with  `Observable.just(loginResponse)`. It should be something like `Single.just(loginResponse)`

Comment: omg you are amazing. that's correct, dont know why i couldnt figure it out. +25 for you

Comment: any idea about my question about uploading an image to server? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req